# Failed executing gradlew using PHP exec() through browser

Tags: php, curl, browser, exec, gradlew

I want to run `gradlew` using PHP. What I have tried is using `exec(), shell_exec,` or `passthru`. I executed those commands inside a PHP script named *"build.php"*. I tried calling the script from a browser or *curl* and got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
```

However when I called it from command line using `php build.php`, it worked very well.

So, I need the `gradlew` command to be executed through user action from browser. My question: what might cause this error and how to get rid of it?

**UPDATED**

This is what build.php looks like:

```
<?php

// some sorts of code ...

$alias = 'myalias';
$storepass = 'mypassword';
$keypass = 'mypassword';

$keystore = str_replace('.', '_', $packageName);
$exec = 'keytool -genkey -noprompt -keystore '.$keystore.'.keystore -alias '.$alias.' -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=kahfi, OU=ID, O=yanmii, L=jogja, ST=diy, C=ID" -storepass '.$storepass.' -keypass '.$keypass;
echo $exec;
$output = '';
exec($exec, $output);
print_r($output);

passthru("./gradlew assembleRelease 2>&1");

?>
```

Comment: Probably there are a problem with permissions. When you run by terminal you run the script as your username, when you run through apache the script is run as another user (www, www_data, ... )

Comment: Better to show the script.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I've updated my post to show the script